# How can I stop the blog posts permalink clashing with blog page permalink in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I'm setting up a website using Jekyll and I'm struggling with the permalink structure. I have a main page for the blog section, listing all the posts, and I want the posts to have urls based on that. For example, the blog page url is

http://example.com/blog/

then the posts should have a url

http://example.com/blog/my_post_title/

However, when I set the posts permalink to

```
permalink: /blog/:title
```

in either the _config.yml file or in an individual post file, the main blog page stops displaying. Instead you get a page with "Index of /blog/" at the top and a WEBrick line at the bottom.

I get the same behaviour if I try setting the category of a post to blog using

```
category: blog
```

Is it possible to have the posts under main page like that or do they have to have a completely unique url?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

To have Jekyll posts under the blog directory use the *baseurl* option in *_config.yml*:

```
baseurl: /blog
```

> Base URL - Serve the website from the given base URL

Then set the permalink as "title" only:

```
permalink: /:title
```

## Update based on comments

If you put `permalink: /blog/:title` in a post, it won't work, you need to specify the permalink without placeholders like `/blog/this-is-my-title`.

In this case I would create a directory called `blog`, and all the posts will be in `blog/_posts`.

Then in `_config.yml` the permalink as: `permalink: /:categories/:title`. So every post in the `blog` folder will have an url like: `/blog/my-post-title`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand. Will setting the base directory not serve the whole site from /blog? Just to be clear, I just want the posts to have a path under /blog, but I also have pages that need to be in the root of the domain.

Comment: I misunderstood your configuration because /blog is a typical place for a jekyll blog, updated the answer!